# Configuring DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Tags: entity-framework

I have been successfully using the following config in my app.config file to set the Entity Framework initialization strategy.

```
<databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[My.DataLayer.MyModelContext, My.DataLayer], [My.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration, My.DataLayer]], EntityFramework"></databaseInitializer>
```

Now I wanted to change it to DropCreateDatabaseAlways but I keep getting an errors when calling update-database or when running the program.

```
<databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`2[[My.DataLayer.MyModelContext, My.DataLayer], [My.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration, My.DataLayer]], EntityFramework"></databaseInitializer>
```

The syntax is exactly the same in with the exception of DropCreateDatabaseAlways vs. MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.

Error:

```
Failed to set database initializer of type 'System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`2[[My.DataLayer.MyModelContext, My.DataLayer], [My.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration, My.DataLayer]], EntityFramework' for DbContext type 'My.DataLayer.MyModelContext, My.DataLayer' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
```

Comment: also..can anyone explain to me the mysterious '2 portion of the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the `` `2 ``  notation you can specify generic arguments.

You need to write `` `2 `` because the [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class has two generic arguments.

But the [DropCreateDatabaseAlways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) only **accepts one generic parameter** `TContext baseAlways<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>`

So you need to writte

```
<databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1[[My.DataLayer.MyModelContext, My.DataLayer]], EntityFramework"></databaseInitializer>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the help about the '2 that was very helpful.  Using your syntax is not dropping the database for me though.

Comment: Which DB are you using? MSSql, SqlCE, LocalDb, etc? How do you know that the DB has not been dropped? EF will recreate the DB with the latest scheme right after the drop.

Comment: I am using localdb. using the update-database command i get error on the first entity create statement indicating that the db already has the object.  So i deleted the db from SQL Server Object Explorer and now notice the seed method not executing.

Comment: If you have some open connections EF not always can drop the DB. If you have something in the `seed` method of the `Migrations.Configuration` it won't run if you are using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`. You need create a custom db initializer with deriving from the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` class and override there the `Seed` method there.

Comment: To save anyone else a google, the ``2 ` notation is just a matter of using the square brackets to your advantage (`[[type]]` becomes `[[type1],[type2]]`)